# Can't set background color of button using Material Components library

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, material-components-android, material-components

My code:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button_one"
     style="@style/ButtonStyle"
     android:text="@string/button_one" />
```

```
<style name="ButtonStyle">
     <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/background_button_text_color</item>
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_button</item
</style>
```

**background_button.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

**background_button_text_color.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

[image]

I am getting a black background instead of white when the button is pressed. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help?
I am on `1.2.0-alpha06` and using `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`.

Comment: Seems like their issue. Wait for new version. You can raise a issue on google.

Comment: Yeah one of the contributors suggested it was fixed but I'm still not able to get it working. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/889#issuecomment-607281980

Comment: Try to use the `app:backgroundTint` attribute and a selector with the [checked state](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_btn_text_btn_bg_color_selector.xml) and use the style `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your style:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/background_button</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Your selectors should be in color folder

background_button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

text_color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

And add to your button:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

[image] [image]

Colors are mine

Comment: That's not working for me. Are you using MaterialComponents theme?

Comment: Yes, I am using "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: I am using Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar. Can you tell me if you get it working with that theme?

Comment: I changed my theme with Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar. It is still working.

Comment: You can try this =>  <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">

Comment: After chaning android:background to android:backgroundTint I kinda got it working now but the buttons are rounded and a stroke around them. Also there is a ripple when pressed. I just need it to turn white with no ripple. https://i.imgur.com/yvGdYO5.gif

Comment: Adding Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton fixed the issues but they are still rounded. Is there a way to make them square? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @nicoqueijo Just use app:cornerRadius="0dp"

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for the help Kasım and Gabriele!

Answer (score 8):

To work around this issue, do one of the following:

- Add `app:backgroundTint="@null"` in xml or programmatically -
  `btn.setBackgroundTintMode(null);`
- Change Theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` to
  `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge`

Both the solutions works fine [Reference](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/889)

Comment: The Bridge thing helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: It worked perfectly for my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Ran into the same issue, setting `app:backgroundTint="@null"` was what worked for me. See full solution here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/889#issuecomment-621194246

Answer (score 6):

add this into button view

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```