# Can't set backgound color of button changing state_enabled

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, material-components-android, material-components

I have a field for entering a phone number and mask for it. I want the button color to be, for example, black when the mask is not yet fully filled, and yellow when it is filled.

**My button**

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    style="@style/AppTheme.YellowButton"
    android:text="Далее"/>
```

**Style**

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.YellowButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/yellow_mail</item>
    <item name="android:drawable">@color/selector_colored_button</item>
</style>
```

**@color/selector_colored_button**

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/yellow_mail"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

And code for it

```kotlin
MaskedTextChangedListener.installOn(
    editText = editPhone,
    primaryFormat = "[000] [000]-[00]-[00]",
    valueListener = object : MaskedTextChangedListener.ValueListener {
        override fun onTextChanged(
            maskFilled: Boolean,
            extractedValue: String,
            formattedValue: String
        ) {
            buttonNext.isEnabled = maskFilled
        }
    })
```

But the button is yellow all the time, its background does not change. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help?
I'm using `"com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06"` and `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
<item name="android:drawable">@color/selector_colored_button</item>
```

and use:

```
<item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/selector_colored_button</item>
```

you can look my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61366681/8956604)